# Is a custom (partial) installation of LibreOffice possible?

Tags: macos, libreoffice

I have a copies of Apple's iWork applications, and I'm an Office 365 subscriber but neither of these get me a relational database app for Mac.

I want to install LibreOffice Base on my Mac (running OS X El Capitan) but I'm not interested in the rest of the suite—I really don't need a *third* office suite. Is it possible to install only the Base application?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't remove a single component anymore. The reason is, that libreoffice needs all components.

**EDIT:** This was for the windows version I assume its for the OSx version aswell at a later date. and is removed in the 4.2 version

On the libreoffice site you can read: "The option to select which Modules to install has been removed from the Windows Custom install dialog (Andras Timar). The option made little sense (all the modules are included in the program: it was just the Start Menu icons/shortcuts that were suppressed)

Source : https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.2#Installer_.28win_only.29